# Cópia de arquivos com erro: O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado

Tags: cmd, prompt

Estou com um projeto pessoal que visa automatizar o processo de criação de pastas dos serviços que presto. Atualmente meu objetivo está em criar 2 script básicos para o **Prompt** do Windows, onde ele cria automaticamente uma série de pastas padronizadas e copia determinados arquivos comuns de uma pasta predefinida para a pasta recém criada.

Atualmente meu script está o seguinte:

```
@echo off
set /p ano="Entre o Ano a ser criado:"
mkdir %ano%\1.JANEIRO %ano%\2.FEVEREIRO %ano%\3.MARCO %ano%\4.ABRIL %ano%\5.MAIO %ano%\6.JUNHO %ano%\7.JULHO %ano%\8.AGOSTO %ano%\9.SETEMBRO %ano%\10.OUTUBRO %ano%\11.NOVEMBRO %ano%\12.DEZEMBRO
cd %ano%\1.JANEIRO
copy "C:\Users\joao.salvador\Documents\2.SERVIÇOS\00.DOCUMENTOS_PADROES\*.xlsx"
timeout 60
```

O problema é que, quando rodo este Script, o sistema cria as pastas corretamente porém, ao tentar copiar os arquivos devolve a mensagem:

> `O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado.`

A parte mais estranha, é que quando abro o Promt e utilizo o mesmo código de cópia, funciona normalmente, como demonstrado pelo Log abaixo:

```
C:\Users\joao.salvador\Documents\2.SERVIÇOS>copy "C:\Users\joao.salvador\Documents\2.SERVIÇOS\00.DOCUMENTOS_PADROES\*.xlsx"
C:\Users\joao.salvador\Documents\2.SERVIÇOS\00.DOCUMENTOS_PADROES\AVBR_Formulario de Reembolso de Despesas de Viagens - Cartao Corporativo.xlsx
C:\Users\joao.salvador\Documents\2.SERVIÇOS\00.DOCUMENTOS_PADROES\AVBR_Formulario de Reembolso de Despesas de Viagens - Reembolso de Despesas.xlsx
C:\Users\joao.salvador\Documents\2.SERVIÇOS\00.DOCUMENTOS_PADROES\ServiceReport_default.xlsx
        3 arquivo(s) copiado(s).
```

Em minhas pesquisas, verifiquei pessoas citando para ser utilizado o **xcopy** ao invés de **copy**, por ser uma versão mais "estável da mesma, mas tentar, continuo tendo um problema similar onde o mesmo me devolve a mensagem:

> `Arquivo não encontrado  - *.xlsx 0 arquivo(s) copiado(s)`

Alguma ideia do por quê deste comportamento estranho?

**Informações Adicionais:**

- Este script é simplesmente um arquivo com extensão **.cmd**
- Meu sistema operacional é um Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bat
@echo off

%:^{
set/p "_ano=Entre o Ano a ser criado: " || goto %:^{

<con: cd/d "%~dp0" && pushd "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\2.SERVI?OS\00.DOCUMENTOS_PADROES"
set "_mes=JANEIRO,FEVEREIRO,MARCO,ABRIL,MAIO,JUNHO,JULHO,AGOSTO,SETEMBRO,OUTUBRO,NOVEMBRO,DEZEMBRO"

for %%i in (%_mes%)do set/a "_m+=1" & cmd/v/c "md "%~dp0!_ano!\!_m!.%%~i" & >nul copy/b "*.xlsx" "%~dp0!_ano!\!_m!.%%~i""
<con: popd & %__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t 60|echo\Pastas criadas e arquivos *.xlsx copiados para: "%~dp0%_ano%" & goto :eof
```

---

> *Alguma ideia do por quê deste comportamento estranho?*
>  **O uso de `Ç` no nome de sua pasta \2.SERVIÇOS\**
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seu erro pode ser *contornado* usando o curinga **`?`** em substituição ao **`Ç`**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> *Em minhas pesquisas, verifiquei pessoas citando para ser utilizado o **xcopy** ao invés de **copy**, por ser uma versão mais "estável da mesma, mas tentar, continuo tendo um problema similar onde o mesmo me devolve a mensagem:*
>
> **XCOPY** *Copia arquivos e diretórios, incluindo subdiretórios.*
> **COPY** *Copia um ou mais arquivos de um local para outro.*
>
> Não existe versão mais (nem menos) ***estável***
> Substituir **COPY** pelo **XCOPY** não melhora (nem piorar) o resultado.

---

> *A parte mais estranha, é que quando abro o **Promt** e utilizo o mesmo código de cópia, funciona normalmente, como demonstrado pelo Log abaixo:*
>
> Quando usas o prompt, o caminho é digitado corretamente.
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

```bat
rem :: nibir exibição dos comandos no script:: 
@echo off

rem :: Label :^{ para loop :: 
%:^{

rem :: define a variável _ano solicitando o input do usuário :: 
set/p "_ano=Entre o Ano a ser criado: " ...

rem :: caso decorrer erro no input da variável _ano, retorna a solicitar ::
... || goto %:^{

rem :: entra no drive:\pasta onde o script está salvo :: 
<con: cd/d "%~dp0" ... 

rem :: salva a pasta atual e entra e define a pasta de suas planilhas como o primeiro diretorio atual na pilha :: 
... pushd "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\2.SERVI?OS\00.DOCUMENTOS_PADROES"

rem :: define um os meses do ano para uso no loop em conjunto com ações/comandos do() ::
set "_mes=JANEIRO,FEVEREIRO,MARCO,ABRIL,MAIO,JUNHO,JULHO,AGOSTO,SETEMBRO,OUTUBRO,NOVEMBRO,DEZEMBRO"

rem :: for loop mes a mes :: 
for %%i in (%_mes%)do ...

rem :: cria a variváel  _m (mes numeral) :: 
set/a "_m+=1" ... 

rem :: invoca o cmd forçando a atualização do valor das variáveis _ano e _m em tempo de execução para o comando que se segue :: 
...cmd/v/c ....

rem :: cria a uma sub-pasta _ano\mês numeral + . + mês literal na mesma pasta onde o bat se encontra %~dp0 
na mes

cria a pasta atualmente em loop do mês (%%~i == literal), concatenado o  numeral _m + \ + . 
"md "%~dp0!_ano!\!_m!.%%~i" ... 

rem :: copy 1 ou mais arquivos da pasta atualmete em uso no pushd para pasta em loop do mes :: 
copy/b "*.xlsx" "%~dp0!_ano!\!_m!.%%~i""

rem :: restaura a pasta salva anteriormente pelo comando pushd
<con: popd ... 

rem :: faz a execução de um timeout em "backgound" redirecionado a saída para a execução do comando echo\ :: 
 %__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t 60|echo\Pastas criadas e arquivos *.xlsx copiados para: "%~dp0%_ano%" ...

rem :: sai da execução do script indo para o final do arquivo [End Of File] :: 
... goto :eof
```

---

Algumas sugestões de leituras adicionas:

- **[Usando cmd /?](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd)**
- **[Usando POPD](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/popd)**
- **[Usando CHCP](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp)**
- **[Usando copy](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy)**
- **[Usando xcopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy)**
- **[Usando PUSHD](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/pushd)**
- **[Usando Curingas](http://bloghardwaremicrocamp.com.br/sem-categoria/script-windowsdos-parte-5-caracteres-curingas/)**

---

- Algumas leituras adicionais (`/English`):

  [√] **[For /?](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)**

  [√] **[Goto :Label](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.htm)**

  [√] **[Escape Characters](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)**

  [√] **[Redirection |, <, > 2>, ...](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√] **[How does the Windows Command Interpreter cmd.exe Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)**

  [√] **[How-to: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes at the Windows command line](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)**